# Ignoring ICS' font size setting

Tags: android, font-size, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I have an Android app that looks absolutely horrible if the user sets their font size to large or extra large (via Settings -> Display -> Font size in Ice Cream Sandwich). It just plain wasn't designed for variable font sizes, and it makes a lot of the text unreadable.

I've seen applications that preserve the font size for most views, so I know that there has to be a way to do this. Is there a simple way for me to tell the application to ignore the user's font size preference? And if there isn't, how would you suggest that I go about calculating the font sizes? If nothing else, is there a way for me to retrieve the user's font size preference?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think what you want to do is specify your font sizes in "dp" instead of "sp". All sp units take user font size preferences into account when adjusting their size, while dp units only calculate size based on the device's pixel density.

Comment: Please, don't do it often. People with vision problems (like me) prefer ugly fonts instead of not being able to read anything at all.